# Детский вопрос: какие животные табунятся?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Ребёнок (шесть лет) знает, что птицы летают в стае, коровки пасутся в стаде, а лошадки — в табуне (до косяка и отары мы пока не дошли).
Только лошади — в табуне? Растерялась; полезла в словари; объяснила.

У Ефремовой:
[**табу́н**](https://www.efremova.info/word/tabun.html#.W8e-TPZuLIU)
1. 1. Стадо лошадей, оленей, верблюдов и некоторых других копытных животных.

Последовал следующий вопрос: а **кто же ещё** — эти "некоторые другие животные"?
Совсем растерялась. Подскажите.

Answer (score 2):

Ну как минимум все родственные лошадям и верблюдам виды и роды - ламы, зебры, ослы (это в чем уверен). А как максимум - насколько понимаю, это применимо вообще ко всем одомашненным вьючным животным. А вот в отношении диких - тут уже надо разбираться. Главное условие - чтобы вместе паслись.

Answer (score 1):

Нет какого-то жёсткого однозначного разграничения. И я даже не знаю, стоит ли в данном случае детям "рассказывать правду".

С одной стороны, многих шокирует во взрослом возрасте, что слова **табун, стадо** применимы к птицам (утки, гуси, лебеди и т.д.), а слово "косяк", например, к лошадям. И тому подобное. Лучше бы, наверное, узнавать это в детстве.

С другой стороны, если ребёнок скажет в школе "табун гусей", некоторые станут смеяться над ним, а учитель может снизить оценку (я сталкивался с таким).

Может, лучше объяснять всё честно, показывать академические словари и говорить ребёнку, что в обиходе есть некоторые условные границы, которые как раз и обозначены в более простых словарях. Решать Вам.

Comment: Пусть с опозданием (чегой-то я пропустила), но — спасибо за ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

> Стадо лошадей, оленей, верблюдов и некоторых других копытных животных.

(Ефремова)

Возможно, также будет интересно, что табуном называют и неорганизованную группу людей (см. там же), а также при некоторых условиях и просто людей, вспомните известные цветаевские строки:

Богиня Иштар, стреми мой табун
В тридевять лун!

Answer (score 1):

Табун - это стадо которое может ускакать), поэтому все перечисленные и прочие олени, антилопы тоже подойдут. Ну и если видео про животных смотрели, то животные табунятся - это как роятся, только не летая, определенный вид быстрого перемещения внутри стада - перемешивания, когда когда хищнику сложно сфокусироваться на одной особи. Коровы на такое неспособны, так как их скорость меньше, они редко бегают без нужды и обычно передвигаются шагом, а табунящиеся бегают, прыгают и скачут. Для защиты от нападения коровы используют рога, а табунящиеся животные - ноги. Роение птиц называется [мурмурация)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4f_1_r80RY).

То есть роение - это коллективная стратегия ряда подвижных животных в больших группах, таких как: насекомые, птицы, копытные, рыбы. Но это сейчас всякие ученые такое наизучали. А древние люди некоторые моменты подмечали и без ученых, поэтому частные случаи "роения" могут быть отмечены словами как табун. Хотя табун - это стратегия поведения, а стадо - это общее название для групп травоядных животных, можно сказать стадо лошадей, это не будет ошибкой, однако, но "табун коров" будет неверно.

Лошади, принадлежащие одному Т., не смешиваются с другими и быстро узнают друг друга. Замечено, что лошади одинаковой величины или одной масти легче привыкают друг к другу. Будучи испуган, весь Т. бросается в паническом страхе в бегство, не останавливаясь ни перед какими препятствиями.

Лошади, принадлежащие одному Т., не смешиваются с другими и быстро узнают друг друга. Замечено, что лошади одинаковой величины или одной масти легче привыкают друг к другу. Будучи испуган, весь Т. бросается в паническом страхе в бегство, не останавливаясь ни перед какими препятствиями.

Также в табуне присутствует общность [знакомых животных](https://gufo.me/dict/brockhaus/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BD#:%7E:text=%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%A2.%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%87%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83.%20%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%A2.%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8.) и косяки из самок и жеребят образующиеся вокруг самцов лидеров. Стадо же построено на подталкивании низкоранговых особей, высокоранговыми. Грубо говоря, в табуне бегают за своими, а в стадом ходят, потому что толкают и наступают на пятки другие.

Про гусей же отдельная тема, потому что у них [строй](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVFIr7Kb6OU). Со стадом гусей в языке вышла промашка, потому что это скорее [армия](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfHhjdJe0fc).

Ну хорошо, еще про табуны:

на меил ру кто-то написал что "табун - это вид быстро перемещающихся животных", я бы сказал "вид быстрого перемещения животных". У Даля: "**ТАБУН** *м. конское стадо; табун делится на косяки, по числу жеребцов, со своими кобылами; местами говорят табун белок, гусей, рыбы..*"

Отсюда понятно, почему иногда табуном можно называть и перемещение птиц, но это скорее литературные красивости или местные особенности языка. Слово табун/табунится даёт акцент на характерный механизм защитного движения, убегания, разлетания. В то время как стая летит по своим делам, а стада медленно движутся куда-то.

*"Но в этот момент табун уток-свиязей отвлек его от размышлений. В полдень Васютка поднял с реки табун гусей, ударил по ним картечью и выбил двух (В. П. Астафьев. Васюткино озеро). ... заходит на посадку незримый табун острохвостов. ...Серый спугнул табун косачей и принялся гонять их с дурацким лаем... (Михаил Тарковский. Енисей, отпусти!)."*

И, первобытный видео образ, что такое [**табун**](https://youtu.be/itJHLLrUax8?t=711) какой он есть - жизнь в движении.

Comment: Спасибо за оценку вопроса и ответ! М-м... Мурмурация? Красивое слово — не попадалось. И красивое пернатое действо. P. S. По поводу птичечек (как с этим быть?): *Но в этот момент **табун уток-свиязей** отвлек его от размышлений. В полдень Васютка поднял с реки **табун гусей**, ударил по ним картечью и выбил двух* (В. П. Астафьев. Васюткино озеро). *... заходит на посадку незримый **табун острохвостов**. ...Серый спугнул **табун косачей** и принялся гонять их с дурацким лаем...* (Михаил Тарковский. Енисей, отпусти!). P. P. S. Мне думается, что лишний абзац надо изничтожить.